# How do i install steamos without an operating system?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, bios, steam-os

my gaming computer's main drive recently crashed (the one that had windows 10 installed on it and all my files), so i bought a new hard drive and i want to still Steamos from a USB.

I followed the steps on the the [SteamOS "Build your own"](http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/buildyourown) page, but everytime i select the USB via the bios it spam prints:

> "Reboot and select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media in selected
>   Boot device and press any key"

When i do press a key it just prints out the same thing. someone say it may have to do with the CMOS battery.

edit: When i select it from the BIOS is does not say "UEFI: steamos drive" like of the example they have on there site is just reads “USB:”

Comment: Either your computer isn't properly booting from the USB drive, or the USB drive wasn't set up with the proper boot files.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator hmm I read on one guide that you have to make a boot record for it, but the official site doesn’t say anything about it. should I try that?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. In order for the USB disk to boot, it needs a valid boot record, so maybe that's what you need. Can't hurt to try.

Comment: SteamOS is the operating system.  So you typically wouldn’t want to have an existing operating system

Comment: @Ramhound I installed steamos once before on my friends computer but he had windows 10 on it so i didn’t know if that had something to do with it

Comment: "steamos drive" is the volume label on their thumbdrive. yours will vary, depending on the label on your volume. You do not need to install a boot record, but you do need your thumbdrive to be partitioned with an MBR partition table, and the first volume must be FAT32. if given the option, set the partition as "Active". Also, per the instructions you must be using UEFI, not BIOS. can you confirm that your firmware is set to UEFI, the volume is FAT32, and that its the only volume on the thumbdrive?

Comment: @FrankThomas I know it’s set to fat32 but idk about the UEFI setting, im using the drive from before that I used on my friends pc and it work fine then but now it’s not

Answer (score 0):

It takes more than copying files to the USB to make it boot.

I usually use a tool like "Makeboot" or "Universal USB Installer" but those ask for an ISO to make the bootable drive from. Since Steam doesn't give you an ISO it looks like you'll have to make it bootable yourself. That is why Steam's instructions ask you to copy the files to an MBR Partition.

I haven't done that myself, but this Youtube video seems to be a good source:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ievfLSUXu2s

Be very careful with such tools as DISKPART as you can easily erase the wrong drive on your computer.

Comment: Steam does have an ISO. But I don’t believe the ISO has the installer on it.

Comment: In that case I'd just use those two programs I mentioned and have them make the USB bootable, it would be much easier. I've used them lots myself.

Answer (score 0):

While it may seem easiest to just install steam os, it might be smarter to try installing Ubuntu first. Ubuntu is similar to steam os, in that there both Linux based, and Ubuntu tends to be the most supported Linux os, but Ubuntu is much easier to install than steam os if you have a working computer, and will help you with if steam os does what you need, or if you want to put windows back on the machine. Windows 10 tends to be motherboard based these days, so installing it on a new hard drive may keep your license functional if you use the same machine otherwise.

Steam os isn't a complete os yet and still is not recommended for beginners to try.

Comment: If the goal is to have a functional _gaming_ Linux PC, I second the recommendation on using Ubuntu instead. It will be much easier to install, and works very well with the Steam client as well as proprietary video drivers (for gaming). Source: I have done this twice recently.